# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED after following "Hosting a Static Website" tutorial

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have been trying to get my domain (nicschmidt.com) working by following this tutorial: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/hosting-static-website#storage-upload-object-client_libraries.

I have done the and double-checked the following:

- create project
- enable billing
- verify ownership of domain (I bought it off of google domains)
- create cname alias
- create bucket
- upload files and share files and folders

If I request the link https://storage.googleapis.com/www.nicschmidt.com/index.html, I can find the index page I uploaded but when I request nicschmidt.com I get the 'nicschmidt.com’s server DNS address could not be found.' page.

Does anyone have any ideas on what might have gone wrong?

I have searched and not found anyone posting of the same issue when hosting a static website via Google Cloud.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the CNAME alias set up correctly:

```
$ dig nicschmidt.com

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49571
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;nicschmidt.com.            IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
nicschmidt.com.     299 IN  SOA ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 5 21600 3600 259200 300

$ dig www.nicschmidt.com

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 57279
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 1, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;www.nicschmidt.com.        IN  A

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
nicschmidt.com.     243 IN  SOA ns-cloud-d1.googledomains.com. cloud-dns-hostmaster.google.com. 5 21600 3600 259200 300
```

Notice that there is no answer section and the status is NXDOMAIN, indicating no record is present. Make sure your DNS provider has the record fully saved.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was, I was trying to create a cname alias via the google cloud console. But I created it via google domains and now it works.

Comment: Do you mean *authorirty* section and not answer section?